# Using Visual Studio 2013 C++ unit test project from outside of VS with a wrapper

Tags: c++, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I'm using Visual Studio 2013 for native Windows C++ development.
I have written a unit test project for the internal unit testing framework.
(Using the TEST_CLASS and TEST_METHOD macros of Microsoft::VisualStudio::CppUnitTestFramework.)
As i understand it, my test code is compiled into a DLL that is used by the VS testing framework.

My question is if and how i can use this DLL to run the test code from within another (inhouse) framework.
This framework can run special console applications, but will use certain conventions for passing arguments, will produce specific logs etc.
So i need to write an exe wrapper that conforms to the inhouse testing framework interface and uses the testing DLL internally.
How would i need to open the DLL, which classes need i to instantiate and which functions to run?
Examples would be great. Didn't find any documentation for that.

PS: To clarify: I know of the possibility to run tests from the command line using VSTest.Console.exe. But this doesn't help, as VSTest.Console.exe does not conform to the interface conventions used by the inhouse testing framework.

Comment: I think you'd have to examine `CppUnitTest.h` that came with your install of Visual Studio to find the function names and relevant `__declspec` that you need for importing symbols. Then you'd link against the dll and be able to call the tests by their exported names. Basically, you need to re-implement VSTest.Console.exe by reverse engineering since the source is not available.

Comment: @AndyG: Yes, that's what it boils down to i guess. I was just hoping that someone else had done it before and could give me some guidance.